How to merge objects in query?
I have 2 custom objects. Let's say its customObj1__c and customObj2__c.
List<customObj1__c> obj1 = [SELECT Id, Name__c, Age__c FROM customObj1__c ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];
List<customObj2__c> obj2 = [SELECT Id, Name__c, Age__c FROM customObj2__c ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];

The problem is how can I merge this so I can get the createdDate by ascending? I am thinking creating a Map by this format: Map<DateTime, Map<String, String>>.. but Map is not in order. All I need to get is the value of this map and put this in the list sorted by createdDate.

You'd need to create a wrapper class that has two instance variables (one for each of your 2 SObjects) so that you can make a single List<MyWrapperClass>. It'd need to have at least 2 constructors.
e.g.
public class MyWrapperClass {
    Account acc;
    OpportunityLineItem oli;

    public MyWrapperClass(Account input) {
        acc = input;
    }

    public MyWrapperClass(OpportunityLineItem input) {
        oli = input;
    }
}

Then, to enable sorting, you'd want to have your wrapper class implement the Comparable interface.
e.g.
public Integer compareTo(MyWrapperClass other) {
    Datetime thisCreated;
    Datetime otherCreated;

    // The null coalescing operator "??", introduced in API v60.0 (Spring '24)
    //   helps make it easy to determine which of acc/oli is populated
    // In a nutshell, if acc is not null, we'll use its createdDate
    //   and if it is null, we'll use oli's createdDate
    // No Safe Navigation Operator on the oli path because with only 2 constructors
    //   in my example, one or the other MUST be populated
    //   (unless you do something like deserialize JSON with neither populated)
    thisCreated = acc?.CreatedDate ?? oli.CreatedDate;

    // Same thing for the "other" instance, but we should handle the possibility
    //   of getting a null
    otherCreated = other == null ? Datetime.now() : other.acc?.CreatedDate ?? other.oli.CreatedDate;

    if(thisCreated < otherCreated) { return -1; }
    else if(thisCreated > otherCreated) { return 1; }
    else { return 0; }
}


@Saber because compareToEmp is an instance of MyWrapperClass, which in my example doesn't have a createdDate instance variable. You'll need to have logic to determine which of the two instance variables is populated in both this and compareTo, extract the createdDates for both into local variables, then do the comparison.

I got it that's why I deleted the comment. However, this is the new code but I'm not able to get the Id of the object

//ImplementthecompareTo()methodpublicIntegercompareTo(ObjectcompareTo){MyWrapperClasscompareToEmp=(MyWrapperClass)compareTo;IdobjId=compareTo.Id;StringobjName=String.valueOf(objId.getSObjectType());if(objName=='Account'){if(acc.CreatedDate==compareToEmp.oli.CreatedDate)return0;if(acc.CreatedDate>compareToEmp.oli.CreatedDate)return1;return-1;}elseif(objName=='OpportunityLineItem'){if(acc.CreatedDate==compareToEmp.acc.CreatedDate)return0;if(acc.CreatedDate>compareToEmp.acc.CreatedDate)return1;return-1;}return0;}

will update my post instead if this is not readable

@Saber again, compareTo is an instance of MyWrapperClass, which doesn't have an Id instance variable in my example. You need to determine which of the two object variables are populated, then get the Id from that (or create an instance variable and populate it in the constructor).

will this work?  DST_CombineDoc toCompare = (DST_CombineDoc) compareTo;
if (this.createDt < toCompare.createDt) {
return -1;
} else if(this.createDt > toCompare.createDt) {
return 1;
} else {
return 0;
}

this is my instance variable:     Account acc;
OpportunityLineItem oli;
public DateTime createDt;

Hi thanks so much! Appreciate it a lot
